# Where is my ubuntu folder?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to install Linux for a small project, however, I use Windows as my primary software on my computer. So, naturally, I searched up some tutorials, and have downloaded Linux/Ubuntu 16.04 as a distro. After unpacking this distro, and following the instructions to set up Ubuntu, I have encountered a small problem while doing so.

It appears that I have no folders whatsoever. Now, I can see all the folders in the Linux shell, I can see this: `bin  boot  dev  etc  home  init  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var`. But in my windows file explorer, I can't find a single file.

I have searched for these in my C: folder, but I can find no trace of them. I also need Linux to access another folder on my computer, but I don't know where to put it anymore. A screenshot is attached below. [image: A screenshot of what I typed and I seem to have all the files]

[image: This is the Windows file explorer structure, which doesn't have the files in it.]
As you can see, Linux shows there is, in fact, all the necessary files. But they aren't present in the Windows file explorer (And yes, I did scroll down).

Maybe I'm just being dumb, but I don't know what to do. Can I get some help?

Comment: Windows has no native support for Linux partitions so you won't see them. But you don't need to do anything. Actually the less you mess with one OS partitions from outside the better.

Comment: I really need a few files to be accessed by Ubuntu, but they are on the Windows partition. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Now, from Ubuntu you can see everything because Ubuntu supports the NTFS partitions where Windows is installed. But, again, better NOT touch the Windows **system** partition. If you need to share files use a separated data partition, also NTFS, so it can be accessed for both. In any case disable the Fast Startup feature in Windows

Comment: So to do this, I have to download an NTFS partition for Windows *and* disable the Fast Startup feature on Windows? If so, what NTFS partition would you recommend I download and how would I go about disabling the Fast Startup feature? (I'm sorry, but I'm pretty new to Ubuntu)

Comment: No. Honestly, you need to learn a lot more than you do now because you'll end up making a mistake you'll regret. I suspect this right after reading *searched for these in my C: folder* and *download an NTFS partition* was the final nail in the coffin. **Use a USB stick**, you can't go wrong with one of those. Keep it plugged in, copy everything you need to it, reboot into the other OS, read/write, do what you want with it, reboot again to the previous OS, no harm done.